# Custom URL Scheme for Support URL

Tags: ios, email, app-store

When submitting app to AppStore you must provide a Support URL. According to docs:

> A URL that provides support for the app you are adding. This will be
>   visible to customers on the App Store

Basically what you provide there is opened in Safari when user press App Support button from App Store. However we all know that iOS support custom URL scheme for mail. For example following will open mail client with predefined address mySupportMail@provider.domain:

```
mailto:mySupportMail@provider.domain
```

So here goes my question. As I could provide sophisticated web page in which user can eventually navigate to my support mail, may I directly put this custom URL in Support URL so when user taps support, he/she will be directly transferred to mail client with provided mail address? I want to know if this scheme will work, and eventually if someone knows if this is violating some Apple rule?

Comment: I'm almost positive that does not work/won't be accepted, and I also don't think it's desirable. That's not what people will expect to happen, and I know I wouldn't *want* to send such an email.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Apple wants you to enter the URL of your app support page on your website, not a custom URL that redirects to some app, or that contains a mailto.